# Subscript out of bound error in R

Tags: r, factor-analysis

While Using `factanal` function from **stats** package for performing factor analysis.

I tried following thing.

```
library(mirt)
library(ltm)
library(psych)
library(stats)
data(SAT12)
data=SAT12
cor_mat=polychoric(data,  ML=TRUE, global=F)
 fit <- factanal(factors=2, n.obs=nrow(data), covmat=cor_mat$rho)


Divide_item_Factor_Loading(fit)
```

when I am trying to run Divide_item_Factor_Loading(fit)  an error called

```
   Error in a[[i]][[2]] : subscript out of bounds
```

pops up.

my complete code of Divide_item_Factor_Loading:

```
Divide_item_Factor_Loading=function(fit)
{
  a=list()
  items=NULL
  for(i in 1:nrow(fit$loadings)) ######corresponding to rows of loading matrix
  {
    k=which(fit$loadings[i,]==max(abs(fit$loadings[i,])))  
    a[[i]]=c(i,as.numeric(k))
  } 
  fact_item_mat=matrix(, nrow=nrow(fit$loadings), ncol=ncol(fit$loadings))
  for(j in 1:(ncol(fit$loadings)))
  {
    for(i in 1:(nrow(fit$loadings)))
    {
      if(a[[i]][[2]]==j) {fact_item_mat[i,j]=a[[i]][[1]]}
    }    
  }
  nam=names(fit$loadings[,1])
  factor=list()
  for(i in 1:ncol(fit$loadings))
  {
    factor[[i]]=sort(fact_item_mat[,i], decreasing = FALSE, na.last = NA)
    fac=factor[[i]]
    fac=nam[fac]
    factor[[i]]=fac
  }
  names(factor)=paste("factor", 1:ncol(fit$loadings), sep="")
  return(factor)
}
```

What steps should I take now to avoid this error?

Comment: As Andrei says this is just the print method - all values are in the loadings matrix. Look at `loadings(fit)` and `loadings(fit)[]`. They look different because of the print method but the loadings matrices are the same. Check `str(loadings(fit))` and `str(loadings(fit)[])`. Another check `loadings(fit)[] == loadings(fit)`

Comment: @Irri, passing your code on the `LSAT` data doesn't give me any error (just a warning though "The ML option has been removed from the polychoric function in the psych package.  Please fix the call") and doing `Divide_item_Factor_Loading(fit)`, I get  `$factor1 [1] "Item 5" $factor2 [1] "Item 1" "Item 2" "Item 3" "Item 4"`. So, I'm sorry, but I don't really understand your question...

Comment: @CathG, can you please provide me your e-mail i.d. so that I can give you the problematic data set.

Comment: @Irri, I wouldn't expect it to be the solution. You really should reformulate your question because you're giving 2 examples that work... Instead, you should give a minimal repoducible example that results in the error you get (and give the expected output). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are some advices that could help you.

Comment: @CathG, I have edited my question again. I hope this one will help you to reproduce the error which I am getting.

Comment: @CathG,  that message is just a warning message telling that not all items in the data set have equal number of categories, which is fine as we have set "global" parameter as False. ( we have to set "global" parameters as False if all the items do not have equal number of categories ). So it is not harmful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your code and debugging your function (using `debug` function) I can see why you're having a "subscript out of bound" error:

- the 15th element (among other) of your variable `a` is of length 1 so `R` is not happy when you're trying to reach `a[[15]][2]`...
- the reason why this element is only of length one instead of 2 is because the maximum absolute value of factor is reached for a negative value and you're asking which value (not absolute) is equal to this maximal absolute value, so the answer is none...

Hence you need to change the line
 `which(fit$loadings[i,]==max(abs(fit$loadings[i,])))` to `which(abs(fit$loadings[i,])==max(abs(fit$loadings[i,])))`
and you'll get:

```
Divide_item_Factor_Loading(fit)
#$factor1
 #[1] "Item.1"  "Item.4"  "Item.6"  "Item.7"  "Item.8"  "Item.9"  "Item.10" "Item.11" "Item.13" "Item.14" "Item.15"
#[12] "Item.17" "Item.19" "Item.20" "Item.24" "Item.26" "Item.27" "Item.28" "Item.29"

#$factor2
 #[1] "Item.2"  "Item.3"  "Item.5"  "Item.12" "Item.16" "Item.18" "Item.21" "Item.22" "Item.23" "Item.25" "Item.30"
#[12] "Item.31" "Item.32"
```

Even if the debugged function will now work, I think you should change it because this is more complicated than it should be.

***My proposition for an alternative function:***

```
Divide_item_Factor_Loading_v2<-function(fit){
     a<-apply(fit$loadings,1,function(facs) which(abs(facs)==max(abs(facs))))
     return(list(factor1=names(a)[a==1],factor2=names(a)[a==2]))
}
```

This gives for your `fit` object the exact same result as your (debugged) function:

```
Divide_item_Factor_Loading_v2(fit)
#$factor1
 #[1] "Item.1"  "Item.4"  "Item.6"  "Item.7"  "Item.8"  "Item.9"  "Item.10" "Item.11" "Item.13" "Item.14" "Item.15"
#[12] "Item.17" "Item.19" "Item.20" "Item.24" "Item.26" "Item.27" "Item.28" "Item.29"

#$factor2
 #[1] "Item.2"  "Item.3"  "Item.5"  "Item.12" "Item.16" "Item.18" "Item.21" "Item.22" "Item.23" "Item.25" "Item.30"
#[12] "Item.31" "Item.32"
```

Comment: @Irri, you're welcome, keep the `debug` function in mind, it is very helpful when you've got a function producing an error ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To change the way the loadings are printed, use the `cutoff` argument to `print.loadings`.

Try something like this:

```
print(fit$loadings, cutoff=0)
```

The actual matrix contains all the values.

```
print(loadings(fit), cutoff=0)

Loadings:
       Factor1 Factor2
Item 1 0.014   0.418  
Item 2 0.130   0.350  
Item 3 0.036   0.553  
Item 4 0.166   0.294  
Item 5 0.990   0.125  

               Factor1 Factor2
SS loadings      1.025   0.705
Proportion Var   0.205   0.141
Cumulative Var   0.205   0.346
```

Now extract the maximum loading on each factor, using `apply()`:

```
apply(loadings(fit), 2, max)

  Factor1   Factor2 
0.9895743 0.5531770
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not want to print it . I need to store that loading matrix in a object and use it to calculate the maximum magnitude of  the loading for an item among factors as I have shown in the code above in the edited question.

Comment: Well, all the loadings are stored.  They just get suppressed when printing.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank your response Andrie. But I need to store the Factor with  the maximum loading for each item. That is what list "a" is doing. Not just one maximum from each factor.  But unfortunately  it is failing to compare the values (And I thought the values are invisible that is why it is not able to compare). I will edit my question again.please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check `?loadings`, what you'll find out that there is a `cutoff` parameter that defines a value that "loadings smaller than this (in absolute value) are suppressed".