# Restricting the length of horizontal line in plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a horizontal line on a plot using `abline`

code is as follows:

```
plot(c(-2,3), c(-1,5), type = "n", xlab = "x", ylab = "y", asp = 1)
abline(h = 0, v = 0, col = "gray60")
```

The output I am getting is

[image: Graph I am getting]

What I am looking for
 is

[image: Desired polt]

How can I make the lines drawn by `abline` are restricted within plot area as shown in 2nd figure.

Comment: Can't reproduce your error. My guess is that you previously set `par(xpd=NA)`, which allows you to draw outside the plot area. If you re-set `par(xpd=F)` then all drawings will be cut to the plot area as in your 2nd plot. See `?par`

Comment: @koekenbakker, you must mean to set `par(xpd=F)` ? because setting `par(xpd=T)` will make the lines go outside of plotting area...

Comment: @CathG yeah I found out already. I always mix up the xpd options ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To develop the comments about how the `xpd` parameter:

***From `par` help:*** the `xpd` parameter is *"A logical value or NA. If FALSE, all plotting is clipped to the plot region, if TRUE, all plotting is clipped to the figure region, and if NA, all plotting is clipped to the device region"*

***Illustration:***

```
par(xpd=T)
plot(c(-2,3), c(-1,5), type = "n", xlab = "x", ylab = "y", asp = 1)
abline(h = 0, v = 0, col = "gray60")
```

gives :

[image]

while

```
par(xpd=F) # this is the default value
plot(c(-2,3), c(-1,5), type = "n", xlab = "x", ylab = "y", asp = 1)
abline(h = 0, v = 0, col = "gray60")
```

gives :

[image]

And finally,

```
par(xpd=NA,mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(c(-2,3), c(-1,5), type = "n", xlab = "x", ylab = "y", asp = 1)
abline(h = 0, v = 0, col = "gray60")
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: will you please be kind to answer  this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321135/how-to-make-appear-all-the-factor-loadings-when-using-factanal-in-r